# wp_get_nav_menu_items not working on translating site in other language

Tags: wordpress, menu, wpml

I have a custom menu from wordpress > Appearance > Menus and bind submenus from db using wp query. The issue i am facing that the submenus are binding in Default Languange (English) but when i translate site in Hebrew Language then submenus are not binding. I checked code and found that wp_get_nav_menu_items filter is not working in hebrew language.

Here is my code :

```
$menu_name = 'Main Navigation';
$name_of_menu_item_to_append_to = 'Where can I use it';
$id_of_menu_item_to_append_to = get_wp_object_id( $name_of_menu_item_to_append_to, 'nav_menu_item' );
global $wpdb;
$get_continents = $wpdb->get_results
(
   "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "continents ORDER BY continent_id ASC"
);

if(count($get_continents) > 0)
{
   foreach ($get_continents as $continent)
   {
     $new_submenu_item = array(
        'text' => $continent->continent_name,
        'url'  => '#'
     );
     add_subitems_to_menu($menu_name,$id_of_menu_item_to_append_to,array( $new_submenu_item ),$continent->continent_id);
   }
}


function add_subitems_to_menu( $menu_name, $parent_object_id, $subitems, $continent_id ) {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}
// Use wp_get_nav_menu_items filter, is used by Timber to get WP menu items
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', function( $items, $menu ) 
        use( $menu_name, $parent_object_id, $subitems, $continent_id ) {
    // If no menu found, just return the items without adding anything
    if ( $menu->name != $menu_name && $menu->slug != $menu_name ) {
        return $items;
    }
    // Find the menu item ID corresponding to the given post/page object ID
    // If no post/page found, the subitems won't have any parent (will be on 1st level)
    $parent_menu_item_id = 0;
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $parent_object_id == $item->object_id ) {
            $parent_menu_item_id = $item->ID;
            break;
        }
    }
    $menu_order = count( $items ) + 1;
    foreach ($subitems as $subitem) {
        // Create objects containing all (and only) those properties from WP_Post 
        // used by WP to create a menu item
        $items[] = (object) array(
            'ID'                => $continent_id, // ID that WP won't use
            'title'             => $subitem['text'],
            'url'               => $subitem['url'],
            'menu_item_parent'  => $parent_menu_item_id,
            'menu_order'        => $menu_order,
            'post_name'         => '',
            // These are not necessary, but PHP warning will be thrown if undefined
            'type'              => '',
            'object'            => '',
            'object_id'         => $continent_id,
            'db_id'             => $continent_id,
            'classes'           => '',
        );
        $menu_order++;
    }
    return $items;
  }, 10, 2);
}
```

I hope you understands what i am trying to explain.